# redirect to another vent when have a return before

Tags: javascript, json

I have a form where I'm creating some validation, and one of the validation needs to grab the value from input and check on the server of in my case in a json file if the value exist.

The only issue is that even when it exists and enters to a return state, is being redirected, I have no idea if the `promise` is having something to do with it.

My code is something like:

```
$("#btnclick").click(function(){

    $.getJSON("locations.json", function(json) {

        var locations = _.filter(json, function(o) {
            return o.value == $originLocation;
        });

        if(locations.length <=0){
            console.log("doesnt exist this location origin");

            //stop here
            return;
        }else{
            console.log("Yes it exist");

        }

    });


    window.location = "some link.php";

    // go to another link--> redirect

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think once you reformat your code the error will be more apparent:

```
$("#btnclick").click(function() {
    $.getJSON("locations.json", function(json) {
         var locations = _.filter(json, function(o) { 
             return o.value == $originLocation; 
         });

         if (locations.length <=0) {
             console.log("doesnt exist this location origin");
             //stop here
             return;
         } else {
            console.log("Yes it exist");      
         }        
    });

    window.location = "some link.php";
    // go to another link--> redirect

});
```

window.location always gets called on the click.  Use a promise chain
What I think you're trying to do here is:

```
$("#btnclick").click(function() {
    $.getJSON("locations.json", function(json) {
         var locations = _.filter(json, function(o) { 
             return o.value == $originLocation; 
         });

         if (locations.length <=0) {
             console.log("doesnt exist this location origin");
             //stop here
            return Promise.resolve(true);
         } else {
            console.log("Yes it exist");      
            return Promise.resolve(true);
         }        
    }).then(exists) {
        if (exists) {
            window.location = "some link.php";
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but there is a way without putting the window.location inside? Since there is other code that code affect

Comment: See update.  You need to use a promise chain of some sorts then.